# create password for user with only ssh key

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, rstudio, ssh-keys

I have user on my linux machine. The user logs in using an ssh key. User does not have a password. I want to create a password for this user, as password is required to access an application (R-studio server) I am trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create password for your user, your can use: *`sudo passwd yourUser`*

Answer (score 0):

As per requirement:- `ssh -t udayan@udayan_maurya_machine passwd`

you can give password at the time of login into machine via ssh